# Apply a single Makefile target rule to multiple input files

Tags: makefile

Say I have the following set of inputs:

```
list = foo \
bar \
baz
```

And say I have a rule such as follows:

```
$(somedir)/%:
   # Do something here
```

I know I am able to invoke the rule by statically defining the target and its dependency:

```
$(somedir)/foo : foo
$(somedir)/bar : bar
$(somedir)/baz : baz
```

However, would there be a way to apply this rule to an evergrowing `$(list)` of inputs rather than having to statically define them all?

To be more specific, I am looking for a way to run a rule for each `input` and get an output (which is $(somedir)/`input`). Is this possible in Make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not sure I understand all the details but it seems to me that pattern rules are exactly what you need:

```
$(somedir)/%: %
    # your recipe
```

This tells make that any `$(somedir)/foo` depends on `foo` and is built by the given recipe. Of course, you will also need to tell make which target you want to build:

```
make somedir=there there/foo there/bar
```

Bonus: if you know the list you can add a phony target to build them all at once:

```
list = foo bar baz

.PHONY: all

all: $(addprefix $(somedir)/,$(list))

$(somedir)/%: %
    # your recipe
```

Second bonus: to help writing your recipe you can use [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables): `$@` expands as the target, `$<` as the first prerequisite, `$^` as all prerequisites, etc. So your recipe could resemble this:

```
$(somedir)/%: %
    build $@ from $<
```